# checkbox: checked="checked", but it doesn't work on page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I'm working on a project, and I got a problem with checkbox. This is a mail subscribing function that check/uncheck all subscribers through a checkbox.

The html code just like this:

```
<div class="select_subscribers">
  <div class="everyone">
    <label>
      <input id="select_all_subscribers" name="select_all_subscribers" type="checkbox">
      <strong>Everyone</strong>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="select_subscribers panel_for_selection">
    <label>
      <input id="subscriber_ids_" name="mail[subscriber_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="3">
      John
    </label>
    <label>
      <input id="subscriber_ids_" name="mail[subscriber_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="2">
      Peter
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

The javascript code just like this:

```
$(".extra .select_subscribers .everyone").delegate "input[type='checkbox']", "click", ->
    $(".select_subscribers.panel_for_selection input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked", this.checked)
```

For the first time it works, check an uncheck, then it doesn't work any more. When "select_all_subscribers" checkbox has been checked, the subscriber checkbox has an attribute "checked='checked'", but it doesn't checked on the page.

How can I do?

Comment: jsfiddle with problem http://jsfiddle.net/DQL84/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use .prop() instead of .attr()

```
$(".extra .select_subscribers .everyone").delegate "input[type='checkbox']", "click", ->
    $(".select_subscribers.panel_for_selection input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", this.checked)
```